# Using T[1] instead of T for functions overloaded for T(&)[N]

Tags: c++, coding-style

The [asio::buffer](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_8/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) function has `(void*, size_t)` and `(PodType(&)[N])` overloads.
I didn't want to write ugly C-style `(&x, sizeof(x))` code, so I wrote this:

```
SomePacket packet[1]; // SomePacket is POD
read(socket, asio::buffer(packet));
foo = packet->foo;
```

But that `packet->` looks kinda weird - the `packet` is an array after all.
(And `packet[0].` doesn't look better.)

Now, I think if it was a good idea to write such code. Maybe I should stick to unsafe C-style code with `void*` and `sizeof`?

---

**Upd:** here is another example, for writing a packet:

```
SomePacket packet[1]; // SomePacket is POD
packet->id = SomePacket::ID;
packet->foo = foo;
write(socket, asio::buffer(packet));
```

Comment: "Now, I think if it was a good idea to write such code"  Come again?

Comment: I had to read this like 5 times to figure out what you were doing.  Go with the C-style, because I would have only have had to read this once.

Comment: Actually, http://ideone.com/lWpNT is an interesting idea as well, and is clearer WRT the buffer and object.

Comment: I'm a bit hazy on P.SE's policies, but wouldn't this be a better fit for SO? ICBWT.

Comment: What's ugly about sizeof()?

Comment: @James it's just an old, ugly, unsafe, redundant C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd create a function:

```
template< typename PodType >
whatever buffer(PodType& obj) { return buffer(&obj, sizeof(obj)) }
```

But this is so obvious an omission in [the set of overloads provided](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_4_8/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html), that I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: How do you SFINAE on PodType being, well, a POD type? I believe that any type traits that could do that need some sort of compiler assistance.

Comment: @Lars: Isn't there a `std::is_pod<>` in C++11? (I am not sure, since I haven't played with C++11 yet.)

Comment: Yes, you have `is_pod` in C++11. Boost.Asio hasn't abandoned all the people with C++03 compilers yet. Just because a new language standard appears doesn't mean that everyone magically are on conformant compilers, particularly not for existing products.